# Newbie Center/Set Zoom of Map to cover all visible Markers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am not a java programmer but I am using some code I found to create a map with multiple markers on so that I can display it within my application.  I want the map to be positioned so that it is in the centre of all the markers zoomed out to see them all.  I have found some code that that should do this but I don't know where to put it within the code I have.  I am also a little unsure if the code i have is good and efficient.  Any help would be most appreciated.  The code I believe I need is

```
var markers = [];//some array
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
}

map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

and my code is.....

```
var locations = [
['C1',-36.8604268000000,174.8360801000000,13140,'521 3131','E','Keith','','',6.72],
['C2',-36.9127356000000,174.9177729000000,16638,'535 5710','E','Debra','d@xtra.co.nz','027 1234546',15.59],
['C3',-36.9045042000000,174.8237394000000,28477,'725 5566','E','Yolande','y@a.kiwi.nz','027 1234546',8.31],
['C4',-36.8945087000000,174.8511699000000,25075,'70 5055','E','Vanessa','accounts@b.co.nz','027 1234546',9.44],
['C5',-36.9045042000000,174.8237394000000,25854,'25 5566','E','Yolande','z@f.kiwi.nz','027 1234546',8.31],
['C6',-36.8845042000000,174.8499481000000,21292,'7 3056','E','Paul','p@xtra.co.nz','027 1234546',8.79],
['C7',-36.8927054000000,174.8331774000000,30664,'06695791777','Not Rated','Jackie','admin@xyz.kiwi','027 1234546',8.01],
['C8',-36.9046501000000,174.8236843000000,25146,'789 525 3123','E','Debra','','02027 1234546',8.31],
['C9',-36.9338100000000,174.8967737000000,23342,'9274 4620','E','Janneane','j@adn.co.nz','',15.29],
['C10',-36.9222589000000,174.8529857000000,21336,'333 0793','E','Cynthia','cynthia@vt.co.nz','027 123 935',11.53],
['Test Client',-36.8484597000000,174.7633315000000,13983,'0652988421','E','Mickey Mouse','r@xyz.com','',0.10],
['Test Client 9 ACC',-36.8484597000000,174.7633315000000,27264,'8956398842','E','Matt','kn@ec.com','021 288 9999311',0.10],
['Test Client 6',-36.9316457000000,174.5736167000000,23605,'33 814 9577','E','John','ward@xtra.co.nz','027893068',19.17],
['Test Client 7',-36.8658161000000,174.5801917000000,22566,'44 232 0082','E','Yolanda','sw@stu.co.nz','02374585',16.33],

];

function initialize() {

var myOptions = {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.8484480000000,174.7621910000000),
  zoom: 15,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("default"),
    myOptions);

setMarkers(map,locations)

}

function setMarkers(map,locations){

   var marker, i

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
{

var name = locations[i][0]
var lat = locations[i][1]
var long = locations[i][2]
var code =  locations[i][3]
var phone =  locations[i][4]
var rating =  locations[i][5]
var contact =  locations[i][6]
var contactemail =  locations[i][7]
var contactmobile =  locations[i][8]
var Kms =  locations[i][9]

latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       map: map, title: name , position: latlngset
     });
     map.setCenter(marker.getPosition())

      var content = "Client: " + name + '</p>' + '</h3>' + "Client No: " + code + '</p>' +  '</h3>' + "Telephone: " + phone + '</p>' +  '</h3>' + "Rating: " + rating + '</p>' +  '</h3>' + "Contact Name: " +  contact + '</p>' +  '</h3>' + "Contact Email: " + contactemail + '</p>' +  '</h3>' + "Contact Mobile: " + contactmobile + '</p>' +  '</h3>' + "Kms From Start Point: " + Kms

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()

google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,content,infowindow){
     return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
     };
 })(marker,content,infowindow));
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var markers = []; //some array
var locations = [
  ['C1', -36.8604268000000, 174.8360801000000, 13140, '521 3131', 'E', 'Keith', '', '', 6.72],
  ['C2', -36.9127356000000, 174.9177729000000, 16638, '535 5710', 'E', 'Debra', 'd@xtra.co.nz', '027 1234546', 15.59],
  ['C3', -36.9045042000000, 174.8237394000000, 28477, '725 5566', 'E', 'Yolande', 'y@a.kiwi.nz', '027 1234546', 8.31],
  ['C4', -36.8945087000000, 174.8511699000000, 25075, '70 5055', 'E', 'Vanessa', 'accounts@b.co.nz', '027 1234546', 9.44],
  ['C5', -36.9045042000000, 174.8237394000000, 25854, '25 5566', 'E', 'Yolande', 'z@f.kiwi.nz', '027 1234546', 8.31],
  ['C6', -36.8845042000000, 174.8499481000000, 21292, '7 3056', 'E', 'Paul', 'p@xtra.co.nz', '027 1234546', 8.79],
  ['C7', -36.8927054000000, 174.8331774000000, 30664, '06695791777', 'Not Rated', 'Jackie', 'admin@xyz.kiwi', '027 1234546', 8.01],
  ['C8', -36.9046501000000, 174.8236843000000, 25146, '789 525 3123', 'E', 'Debra', '', '02027 1234546', 8.31],
  ['C9', -36.9338100000000, 174.8967737000000, 23342, '9274 4620', 'E', 'Janneane', 'j@adn.co.nz', '', 15.29],
  ['C10', -36.9222589000000, 174.8529857000000, 21336, '333 0793', 'E', 'Cynthia', 'cynthia@vt.co.nz', '027 123 935', 11.53],
  ['Test Client', -36.8484597000000, 174.7633315000000, 13983, '0652988421', 'E', 'Mickey Mouse', 'r@xyz.com', '', 0.10],
  ['Test Client 9 ACC', -36.8484597000000, 174.7633315000000, 27264, '8956398842', 'E', 'Matt', 'kn@ec.com', '021 288 9999311', 0.10],
  ['Test Client 6', -36.9316457000000, 174.5736167000000, 23605, '33 814 9577', 'E', 'John', 'ward@xtra.co.nz', '027893068', 19.17],
  ['Test Client 7', -36.8658161000000, 174.5801917000000, 22566, '44 232 0082', 'E', 'Yolanda', 'sw@stu.co.nz', '02374585', 16.33],

];

function initialize() {

  var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.8484480000000, 174.7621910000000),
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("default"),
    myOptions);

  setMarkers(map, locations)
}

function setMarkers(map, locations) {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var marker, i

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

    var name = locations[i][0]
    var lat = locations[i][1]
    var long = locations[i][2]
    var code = locations[i][3]
    var phone = locations[i][4]
    var rating = locations[i][5]
    var contact = locations[i][6]
    var contactemail = locations[i][7]
    var contactmobile = locations[i][8]
    var Kms = locations[i][9]

    latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      title: name,
      position: latlngset
    });
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition())

    var content = "Client: " + name + '</p>' + '</h3>' + "Client No: " + code + '</p>' + '</h3>' + "Telephone: " + phone + '</p>' + '</h3>' + "Rating: " + rating + '</p>' + '</h3>' + "Contact Name: " + contact + '</p>' + '</h3>' + "Contact Email: " + contactemail + '</p>' + '</h3>' + "Contact Mobile: " + contactmobile + '</p>' + '</h3>' + "Kms From Start Point: " + Kms

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, content, infowindow) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      };
    })(marker, content, infowindow));
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#default {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?"></script>
<div id="default"></div>
```